# Recognize Repeated Movement Patterns of Mouse Behavior using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, mouse, data-mining, weka

I have a situation where I have collected mouse movement points from a website. I have a series of (x, y)-points, and I need to detect different repeated patterns of mouse movement from this data. For example, mouse moving very slowly, mouse moving very fast toward a direction and then stopping for a while, mouse scrolling etc... I need to detect such patterns from my data.

Is there a way to do that with OpenCV ...or maybe some other Library?

P.S. Please keep in mind, that I am a beginner in this kind of stuff.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to add further details. Since you are talking about speed, hope  you have what time the positions are measured. But what about scrolling? if mouse stand still and scroll, how can you be sure if it is standing still or it is scrolling? It will be good if you add some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although OpenCV does have some good data analysis and machine learning algorithms, it is really a library geared toward computer vision (thus the CV name). It sounds like you have already done the data capture, and now you want to perform what is called [data mining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mining).

Data mining toolkits have many more tools and algorithms for this type of analysis than does OpenCV, so I would point you toward those. A good open-source toolkit to get started with is [Weka Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/weka/) and [Weka Home](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/index.html). It is written in Java, so it will run on just about anything. [Here](http://iweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/weka/documentation/3.6.x/WekaManual-3.6.0.pdf) is the manual for Weka 3.6.0. There is also a good book available to help get you started using Weka available [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123748569).

Since you are a beginner, do understand that the learning curve for data-mining can seem a bit steep at first, but just take it slowly :) Maybe as a first project, just try to cluster the different (x, y) positions, then use some of Weka's visualization tools to see where the users are placing the mouse on the screen.

Once you are comfortable enough to perform basic clustering, then come back with more questions. Also, [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) (a stackexchange site dedicated to statistics and data-mining) is where you'll want to direct future questions on this subject.

Hope you find this information helpful!